# Evaluate the line segment intergal

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the line integral 
$$\int_C xe^{y}\, {\rm d}s,$$

where $C$ is the line segment from $(-1,2)$ to $(1,1)$.

I do not get this part of calculus at all please show me how this is solved and if you give me hints is ok too. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: A good starting point would be to better describe $C$ - can you give a parametrization?

Comment: @jainsmit: Please make sure I edited this correctly. Regards

Answer (score 4):

Parameterize the line segment:

$$\vec{r}(t)=\langle{2t-1,-t+2}\rangle,0\le{t}<1$$

Now the integral becomes as follows:

$$\int_Cxe^yds=\int_0^1(2t-1)e^{(-t+2)}|\vec{r}'(t)|dt$$

Comment: what is the next step?

Comment: @jainsmit Evaluate the one dimensional area integral. Do you know how to take a basic integral of one variable?

Comment: yes I do. I do not get y you put r(t) in the integral though. also how did you do the parameter?

Comment: @jainsmit Because by definition, $ds=|\vec{r}(t)|dt$. You get the parameterization by interpolating between the points, and choosing a $t$ interval. I usually use $0\le{t}<1$ for convenience.

Comment: im still not following you..sorry. can you show me?

Comment: @ZettaSuro: This is wrong. Review your definition of arclength.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you show me?

Comment: @jainsmit You're asking for an entire vector calculus lecture worth of information. Here's a link that explains it pretty thoroughly: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsIntro.aspx

Comment: @TedShifrin I was just missing the derivative sign. It was a simple typo. I've edited.

Comment: so the r'(t) is going to be (2,-1)?

Comment: @jainsmit Yes exactly.

Comment: can you finish the integral so i can follow your step?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9538/discussion-between-zettasuro-and-jain-smit)